# Sum of F() expression and timedelta created from F() expression

Tags: python, django, django-models

My Proposal model is defined as follows:

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
    scheduled_time = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.IntegerField() # stores minutes as an integer

    # (extra fields clipped for brevity's sake)
```

I want to annotate each proposal object, giving it an 'end' datetime calculated by scheduled_time + a timedelta representation of duration, e.g. `timedelta(minutes=duration)`. However, F() expressions don't seem to be valid as an argument to `timedelta()`.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> from schedule.models import Proposal
>>>
>>> proposals = Proposal.objects.all()
>>> annotated = proposals.annotate(
...     end=F('scheduled_time')+timedelta(minutes=F('duration')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: F
>>>
```

Is this sort of thing possible using `annotate()` and F() expressions?

**edit:** The purpose of the annotation is to be able to filter/exclude on the computed end time.

Comment: Looks like `F('duration')` doesn't return a number.. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F()`-expressions works only with django (as they return instances of specific objects). You can't pass them to timedelta or whatever except some of the django queryset methods.

So you'd better add new field to you model:

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
    scheduled_time = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = IntegerField()
    end = models.DateTimeField(default=self.scheduled_time + timedelta(minutes=self.duration))
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably the right way to go. I was hoping someone would chime in with a solution that didn't require modifying the model, but I think the only answer there is to skip the ORM and use SQL.

Comment: I'm sorry but this gives

`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Look at my answer for a possible working solution

Answer (score 1):

F() can't be used that way, as @Daniil already pointed out.

A possible solution is to add a new field

```
end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

and override the save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.end_time:
        self.end_time = self.scheduled_time + datetime.timedelta(self.duration)
    super(Proposal, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```