# Django model - query with date arithmetic on model with multiple DateTimeField fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 3.2

I have a model like this:

```
class FoodItem(models.Model):
    display_date = models.DateTimeField()
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField()
    safe_to_eat_days_after_expiry = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    # ...
```

I want to run a query to get all items that have expired, but are still safe to eat.

This is what I have so far:

```
criterion1 = Q(expiry_date__gt=date.today())
criterion2 = Q(???)  #  expiry_date +timedelta(safe_to_eat_days_after_expiry ) <= date.today()

FoodItem.objects.filter(criterion1 & criterion2)
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert your `safe_to_eat_days_after_expiry` field into a `DurationField` and use either `annotate` or `alias` (New in Django 3.2, won't select the value but can be further used in filters) so that you can use this calculation in your query:

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from django.utils import timezone

FoodItem.objects.alias(
    safe_till=ExpressionWrapper(
        F("expiry_date")
        + ExpressionWrapper(
            F("safe_to_eat_days_after_expiry") * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000, # days to microseconds
            output_field=DurationField(),
        ),
        output_field=DateTimeField(),
    )
).filter(expiry_date__lte=timezone.now(), safe_till__gte=timezone.now())
```

> **Note**: You initialize your field as `PositiveSmallInteger` perhaps this is just a typo while posting but it is actually
> `PositiveSmallIntegerField`. Also since this is a duration it should
> ideally be a `DurationField`. Next you are using a `DateTimeField`
> when perhaps you actually should be using a `DateField` instead.

Comment: Yes, well spotted, the `PositiveSmallInteger` was a typo (corrected now).  I haven't come accross `ExpressionWrappers` before, or alias - will look those up.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli `alias` is a new feature in Django 3.2 as I said in the answer, you can use `annotate` instead if you use an older version. The only difference is that `annotate` would select the value and you can access it on the objects whereas `alias` won't select the values but allow you to use them in filters, other annotations, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are multiplying the DurationField Value by 1000000 - is the unit in milliseconds?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli that is because the unit is in microseconds, I have added a comment in the code. :)

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli also had made a minor mistake in the logic changed `safe_till__lte` to `safe_till__gte`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs I found that you could do a raw sql, so i guess something like this might work, just the myapp part change it for the name of your app.

```
FoodItem.objects.raw('''SELECT *
                       FROM myapp_fooditem
                       WHERE display_date>=DATEADD(day, expiry_date, display_date)''')
```

Ill recommend adding the field to the model and modifying your save method to be saved by default:

```
FoodItem(models.Model):
    ....
    safe_to_eat = models.DateTimeField()



def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.safe_to_eat:
        self.safe_to_eat= self.expiry_date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.safe_to_eat_days_after_expiry)
    super(FoodItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'd rather not use Raw SQL if I can help it.

Comment: By the way im suggesting that because of the timedelta piece, i referred to this original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835870/sum-of-f-expression-and-timedelta-created-from-f-expression

Comment: I've just seen your comment about modifying the model - unfortunately, I can't because it `FoodItem` is an abstract class that is used in a multiple inheritance relation - (and one of the child classes calls `save()` as well).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me on Django 3.2 + Postgres 12, failing with:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + smallint
LINE 1: ...id") WHERE ("xxx"."created" + "xxx ...
                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Upon inspecting the generated query, I noticed that Django does not convert the duration field to `interval`, but instead tries to perform a naive addition:

```sql
WHERE ("xxx"."created" + "xxx"."days_after") > 2023-03-07 14:27:47.332207+00:00
```

A simpler approach that works on Postgres is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297988/909800):

```py
now = timezone.now()

FoodItem.objects.filter(
    expiry_date__lte=now, 
    safe_till__gte=now + timezone.timedelta(days=1) * F('safe_to_eat_days_after_expiry')
)
```